# Prevent Android function call from running before its predecessor completes?

Tags: java, android, parallel-processing, countdown

I am running a main function that calls three others in succession like this:

```
public void test() {
   countdown(); 
   secondMethod(); 
   lastMethod(); 
}
```

But before my call from within countdown() ie intermediateFunction() is compete, secondMethod runs. Countdown contains a timer that calls another function before it completes, like this:

```
public void countdown() {
    new CountDownTIme(3000, 1000) {
         public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                text.setText( Long.toString(millisUntilFinished / 1000);
         }
    }
    public void onFinish() {
         text.setText(" "); 
         intermediateFunction(); 
    } 
 }.start(); 
}
```

How can I get it to run in succession from countdown->intermediate->secondMethod->etc.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call `secondMethod()` from `onFinish()` of `countdown()`.

Comment: Awesome-- it works! I am wondering, though, because I am new to android, is it an okay practice to entangle my functions like this? ie move control through other functions instead of coming back to a "master/main" function?

Comment: @user3693159: The notion of always "coming back to a master/main function" has been generally obsolete for the past 20 years or so, outside of scripting languages. I strongly encourage you to learn object-oriented and event-driven programming. They will help you "detangle" your code a bit more. Beyond that, though, it is difficult to help you more in the abstract.

Comment: Thanks for the insight. I will look into those styles.